# How to fix `error starting agent failed to get advertise address multiple private ips found`

Tags: ubuntu, consul

I want to build a cluster. I tried following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-consul-in-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I got this error. I dont know if it is because I am running 2 ubuntu vm(hyper-v) on the same machine .

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, that you have more than one network interface with private IP and Consul can't select one of them to use it as advertise address. You have to provide it manually with `-bind` property. Something like this:

```
-bind=172.17.0.1
```